# PartialEQ explicit implementation for enum triggers thread 'main' has overflowed its stack

Tags: arrays, struct, rust, enums, stack-overflow

Explicit implementation of PartialEQ for Enum is triggering a stack overflow when having a struct with an array with an enum:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
enum MyEnum {
    A,
}

impl PartialEq for MyEnum {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self == other
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    cells: [MyEnum; 1],
}

fn main() {
    let init_struct = MyStruct {
        cells: [MyEnum::A]
    };

    assert_eq!(init_struct.cells[0], MyEnum::A);
}
```

Output from the terminal:

```
➜  enum-bug git:(master) ✗ cargo run
   Compiling enum-bug v0.1.0 
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.27s
     Running `target/debug/enum-bug`

thread 'main' has overflowed its stack
fatal runtime error: stack overflow
[1]    2361 abort      cargo run
```

But when commenting out the explicit implementation of PartialEQ, and adding it to #[derive] everything works successfully:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
enum MyEnum {
    A,
}

/*
impl PartialEq for MyEnum {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self == other
    }
}
*/

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    cells: [MyEnum; 1],
}

fn main() {
    let init_struct = MyStruct {
        cells: [MyEnum::A]
    };

    assert_eq!(init_struct.cells[0], MyEnum::A);
}
```

So what's wrong with the explicit PartialEQ implementation for the enum?

Comment: What do you expect `self == other` in your implementation to do? Currently, it refers to the `PartialEq` implementation recursively.

Comment: How do you implement explicit the PartialEq otherwise?

Comment: Your `PartialEq` should always return `true`, that's what the implementation generated by `#[derive(PartialEq)]` does. And why shouldn't it? If the enum only has a single unit variant, then one will always equal to another since there's no room for any difference.

Comment: @Cerberus is right. When you use derive, Rust checks if each fields equals which is largely sufficient for simple comparisons. But by trying `self == other` you're actually calling again and again `eq`. So going with the derive form is likely what you want unless your logic is actually different. See the trait docs [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html).

Comment: @kmdreko, you can modify the example to have `enum MyEnum {A,B}` so PartialEQ cannot always return `true` and still get the stack overflow error.

Comment: @kraken @cerberus OK, but you can complicate things here and it still fails, right? ```enum MyEnum {A(isize),B(isize)}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, `==` looks for a `PartialEq` implemetation, so your code infinitely recurses.

Instead, you can use `match`:

```rust
enum Foo {
  A,
  B,
}

impl PartialEq for Foo {
  fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
    match (self, other) {
      (Self::A, Self::A) => true,
      (Self::B, Self::B) => true,
      _ => false
    }
  }
}
```

Though I'd recommend just deriving it for most `PartialEq` implementations, unless you have good reason not to.